# PHP: imap_header does not display Request Read Receipt and Priority headers

Tags: php, email, imap, email-headers

I'm trying to read the Request Read Receipt and Priority headers from email headers via PHP.

IT seems that `imap_header` only displays *select* headers. The message headers below should but do not include the two headers I'm looking for...

```
 stdClass Object ( 
 [date] => Tue, 30 Jul 2013 18:11:26 -0700 (MST)
 [Date] => Tue, 30 Jul 2013 18:11:26 -0700 (MST) 
 [subject] => Return
 Request Receipt + High Priority Test 
 [Subject] => Return Request
 Receipt + High Priority Test 
 [in_reply_to] => <__@mrmail.com>
 [message_id] => <__@mrmail.com> 
 [toaddress] => __@example.com [to] =>
   Array ( 
   [0] => stdClass Object (
     [mailbox] => __ [host] => example.com
   )
 )

 [fromaddress] => Someone <__@mrmail.com> 
 [from] => 
   Array ( 
     [0] =>
       stdClass Object ( 
         [personal] => Someone 
         [mailbox] => example 
         [host] => mrmail.com 
   )
 )

 [reply_toaddress] => Someone <__@mrmail.com> 
 [reply_to] => 
   Array ( 
     [0] => stdClass Object (
       [personal] => Someone 
       [mailbox] => __ 
       [host] => mrmail.com 
      )
 )

 [senderaddress] => Someone <__@mrmail.com> 
 [sender] => 
   Array ( 
     [0] => stdClass Object ( 
       [personal] => Someone 
       [mailbox] => example 
       [host] => mrmail.com 
      )
 )

 [Recent] => 
 [Unseen] => U 
 [Flagged] => 
 [Answered] => 
 [Deleted] =>
 [Draft] => 
 [Msgno] => 69 
 [MailDate] => 30-Jul-2013 19:18:03 -0600
 [Size] => 2719 
 [udate] => 1375233483
```

So what function in PHP do I use to iterate through *ALL* headers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, the array below returns *all* headers, posting for others...

**[edit]** Updated so that headers that may appear more than once are checked and an array with their values are added. The `$unlimited` array is sampled from https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.6.**[/edit]**

```
<?php
$th = imap_fetchheader($mbox,$cms->page2);
$th = trim($th);
$th = str_ireplace("\r","\n",$th);
$th = str_ireplace("\n\n","\n",$th);
$p0 = explode("\n",$th);
$current = '';
$unlimited = array('comments','keywords','optional-field','resent-bcc','resent-cc','resent-date','resent-from','resent-msg-id','resent-sender','resent-to','trace');
$headers = array();

foreach ($p0 as $k1)
{
 $k1 = rtrim($k1);
 $a = $k1;
 $b = trim($k1);

 if ($a!==$b)
 {
  $p1 = trim($k1);
  if (in_array($current,$unlimited)) {array_push($headers[strtolower($current)],$p1);}
  else {$headers[strtolower($current)] .= $p1;}
 }
 else if (stristr($k1,':'))
 {
  $p1 = explode(':',$k1,2);
  if (in_array(strtolower($p1[0]),$unlimited))
  {
   if (!isset($headers[strtolower($p1[0])])) {$headers[strtolower($p1[0])] = array($p1[1]);}
   else {array_push($headers[strtolower($current)],$p1[1]);}
  }
  else
  {
   if (!isset($headers[strtolower($p1[0])])) {$headers[strtolower($p1[0])] = $p1[1];}
   else {$headers[strtolower($p1[0])] .= $p1[1];}
  }

  $current = $p1[0];
 }
}

ksort($headers);//Mainly for testing purposes, remove this afterwards.

echo '<div><pre>';
$a = print_r($headers,1);
echo htmlspecialchars($a).'</pre></div>';
?>
```